# PIC16 Configurable Logic Cell (CLC) - toggle signal

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, pic16f

I have a 1Hz square signal (in_1) and a 1/16Hz pulse (in_2) as inputs of a PIC16F1778. The rising edges of the two signals are synchronous as shown in the picture:
[image]

I want to use the configurable logic cells (CLCs) inside the PIC16 ([datahsheet p.391ff](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC16(L)F1777_8_9_Family_Data_Sheet_40001819D.pdf)). So that I get the output signal (out) as in the picture. The exact timing is very important, so I want to realize it in hardware and not via an interrupt.

I tried it with a J-K flip flop where J and K are both in_2. I thought I can toggle the output of the flip flop that way. But that doesn't work as intended. I just get one pulse every 16 periods that way.
[image]

Can you help me to set up the CLC in such a way that I get the desired output signal? Or is it not possible at all?

Thank you very much for your effort.

Best regards

Momchilo

Comment: in_1 is irrelevant

Comment: I agree. But then I still have the same problem. I just want to toggle in_2 every 16 periods.

Comment: make both J and K high ... connect in_2 to clock (g1)

Comment: Thank you very much. What a simple and good solution. It's working now.